# How/when does the F# compiler read ahead for type inference?

Tags: compiler-construction, f#, inline, type-inference

If I create the add function below

```
let add x y =
    x + y
```

and then separately run the line below, I’ll get an error because F# will by default assume that x and y should be ints.

```
add 5.4 3.2
```

That said, if I run them together, add works just fine since it now sees it as a function that gets two floats (which implies the compiler looked ahead to do type inference).

This begs the question, why doesn’t the same process of looking ahead allow F# to know that toHackerTalk is taking in a string? Even if I run the below lines all together, it gives me an error because the type of phrase is indeterminate.

```
let toHackerTalk phrase =
    phrase.Replace('t', '7').Replace('o', '0')

toHackerTalk "this be strange"
```

Comment: I've heard it said that F# infers left to right, but this (which I've only noticed recently) seems to contradict that (for the better). Maybe they've been working on the type system recently?

Comment: @Jwosty - the behaviour in the question has existed for at least a few years.

Comment: Ah, I never noticed that...

Comment: @Jwosty see my answer for a rough overview of the type inference mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the simple view of this.  In the first case, the compiler knows about `+` (it is defined in F# core) and it simply picks a default type of `int` (which is probably defined in the spec somewhere), if it then sees the `float` usage, a different version of `+` is picked.

On the other hand, the compiler does not have sufficient information to pick a type which has a `Replace` member, so it can't compile the function

Answer (score 1):

The spec alludes to this behavior in section [5.2.3](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818802):

> Uses of overloaded operators do not result in generalized code unless definitions are marked as  inline. For example, the function
>
> ```
>    let f x = x + x
> ```
>
> results in a function f that can be used only to add one type of value, such as int or float. The exact type is determined by later constraints.

Generally speaking, this issue crops up whenever the compiler infers a "generic" definition that can't really be generic for one reason or another.  In the case of using operators like `(+)` there's a static member constraint which prevents `add` from being generic unless it's also declared `inline`.

Another case where this sort of limitation comes up is:

```
let d = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary()

d.[0] <- "test"
```

If you evaluate these lines together, `d` will be a `Dictionary<int,string>`, but if you evaluate them separately you'll get an error when evaluating the second one because `d` will have been inferred to be a `Dictionary<obj,obj>`.  Based on its definition, `d` could be a `Dictionary<'a,'b>` for any `'a` and `'b`, but it's not a generic definition since there's no such thing as a generic value (well, almost; see the use of `[<GeneralizableValue>]` for an exception).

Answer (score 1):

My understanding, based on a long-ago reading of the spec, is that the compiler doesn't actually look ahead, but it rather creates type variables as it goes along, identifying constraints for each variable, and then assigns actual types to the variables after reading everything.  So in the second case, as it reads the add definition, it creates type variables `'a` and `'b` for the arguments.  Then it gets to the call `add 5.4 3.2` which constrains both `'a` and `'b` to be `float`.

When you compile `let add x y = x + y` by itself, there's nothing else to constrain the types, so the compiler picks `int`.

Since the type constraints are resolved after reading the entire compilation unit, one might answer your question by saying "always".  The behavior you're questioning only arises in F# interactive, where compilation units are smaller.  The compilation is done in bits rather than all at once.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `add` the compiler will default the argument types to `int`. If you instead write `let inline add x y = x + y` then the compiler will automatically generalize the types of `x` and `y` to those which implement a `+` operator. This is an example of [statically resolved type parameters](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-generic-numeric.aspx/). When defaulting the parameter types of `add` to `int` F# will look within the current scope.

In the case of `str.Replace` the method `Replace` is an instance method on string. As such, the compiler must know the type of `str` to make any determination about its instance methods. Alternatively, in the example above, `+` is a static function - the compiler knows the types and constraints involved before hand. For more on F# type inference look [here](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/type-inference/).